# Php Insert Data To MySql From Web Form Securely

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am learning php and have been following the OOP creating a data class tutorial at [phpbridge.org](http://phpbridge.org/intro-to-php/adding_topics?back=creating_a_data_class)

In the tutorial they take form data from a post and insert it into the database.

Here is the code:

Step 1:  The Form

```
<h2>New Topic</h2>
<form action="add.php" method="POST">
    <label>
        Title: <input type="text" name="title">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        Description:
        <br>
        <textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Topic">
</form>
```

Step 2 Php file

```
<?php
 require 'TopicData.php';

if (isset($_POST) && sizeof($_POST) > 0) {
    $data = new TopicData();
    $data->add($_POST);
}
?>
```

Step 3

The Function included in TopicData.php

```
public function add($data)
{
    $query = $this->connection->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO topics (
            title,
            description
        ) VALUES (
            :title,
            :description
        )"
    );

    $data = [
        ':title' => $data['title'],
        ':description' => $data['description']
    ];

    $query->execute($data);
}
```

My question is in regards to security.   Before this data is inserted into a database wouldn't it be best practice to run each field of the form through the filter_input() function?  Also should these be run through filter_var() as well?

If this is necessary what exactly would the filter code look like?

Thanks!

Comment: The only reason you filter is if you've got constraints on what can go in any particular field. Do you have any limits on what a title or description can contain?

Comment: @tadman - I don't have limits on the title or description.  However I was under the impression to never access $_Post directly for security always use filter_input() function.  Described here:. https://www.phparch.com/2010/07/never-use-_get-again/

Comment: That article may as well be from the stone age, but it's not all wrong. The thing is you need to constrain to a type, like integer or float or email, but for plain old strings it's more complicated. What's "valid"? You usually need to define that more specifically in your code.

Comment: If you're concerned about validation and having a standardized method of doing that, most [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) have one or more systems for doing that. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), as one example, has quite a comprehensive [data validation system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation) that's not just filtering, but verifying things like min and max length.

Comment: @tadman Thank you your responses are very helpful.  I wish I could find a tutorial building a simple web app with php that provides

Comment: ... security best practice so I can learn the overall concept..  Seems like most of the php books don't cover the security part. Thank you again and also thanks for the tip on Laravel.

Comment: Most PHP books are sadly relics from the past. Modern PHP development strongly steers towards using frameworks, and there's many to choose from. Find one that you like, learn it well, and you'll be far more productive as a programmer. Laravel is just one example, but it's got a tremendous amount of high-quality traing material on places like [Lynda](https://www.lynda.com/PHP-tutorials/Intro-Laravel-5/540346/579858-4.html) or [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com). Other frameworks have their own resources and many are just as good.

Answer (score 0):

The TopicData.php file is using prepared SQL queries. The benefit of using prepared queries is that it removes the possibility of SQL Injection provided that the SQL query is not based on external input. When using prepared queries, the template of the query is sent separately from the data. This has many benefits which are described here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

It removes the need for sanitizing form data. However the form data may still need to be filtered using the filter_var functions, if validation is required such as maximum string length, maximum and minimum values etc.

Comment: @Nadir_Latif,  you stated "provided that the SQL query is not based on external input.". What do you mean by that?   Also would it be safe to say if I use PDO with attribute attr_emulate_prepares, false for all form data submitted to MySQL, that is the best method to prevent sql injection?

Comment: If the SQL query contains variables. For example: `"INSERT INTO $table_name ($field_name1, $field_name2) VALUES ($title_value, $description)"`, then it raises possibility of SQL injection. If the one of the variables used inside the query, for example $table_name or $title_value is  submitted by the user, then he can inject malicious code into the SQL query. When using prepared queries the query should not contain variables. Instead it should use placeholders such as :title or ? like you have done.

Comment: Well the attribute attr_emulate_prepares determines whether the database driver should always use emulated prepared statements. Some database drivers do not support prepared statements. In such cases the PDO emulates the prepared query so there is a consistent interface for accessing database drivers. You should not have to change the default value for attr_emulate_prepares